# Not all but some android devices give bitmap size exceeds 32 bits error

Tags: android, bitmap, android-image

I'm fetching informations and Images from urls with Json(decode) and show them with `CustomListviewAdapter`, but i have a incomprehensible problem, i couldnt find the solution. I dont get any error(my emulators and phone) but some phones is giving `bitmap size exceeds 32 bits error`. I have to solve this problem because my app is on the google play market.

By the way I'm using urlimageviewhelper library to show image from url and using lazy loading.
 Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

**Here are the codes**

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {

            JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(result);
            asd = new String[3][jsonResponse.length()];
            rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject js = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);
                asd[0][i] = js.getString("Category_Name");
                asd[2][i] = js.getString("Image");
                asd[1][i] = js.getString("Term_ID");

                RowItem item = new RowItem(asd[2][i], asd[0][i], asd[1][i]);
                rowItems.add(item);
            }


            adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    R.layout.list_item, rowItems);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**RowItem class**

```
public class RowItem<T> {
private String imageId;
private String title;
private String desc;

public RowItem(String imageId, String title, String desc) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.title = title;
    this.desc = desc;
}
public String getImageId() {
    return imageId;
}
public void setImageId(String imageId) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
}
public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}
public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return title + "\n" + desc;
}
}
```

**CustomListViewAdapter class**

```
  public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {
Context context;
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<RowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtDesc;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());

    ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    ImageView gif = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    Ion.with(gif).load("http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/android-icon/loading.gif");
    Drawable drawable=gif.getDrawable();
    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(img, rowItem.getImageId(),drawable,
            600000);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

**Error Log**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32bits
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:809)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:769)
at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:13649)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13379)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13445)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14223)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3118)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2955)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13398)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13445)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14223)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3118)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2955)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13398)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13445)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14223)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3118)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2955)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13398)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13445)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14223)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3118)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2955)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13398)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13445)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14223)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3118)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2955)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13398)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13445)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14223)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3118)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2955)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13398)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13445)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14223)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3118)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2955)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13398)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13445)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14223)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3118)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2955)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13398)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13445)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14223)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3118)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2955)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14509)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2452)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13403)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13445)
at     android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1570)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2431)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2301)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1047)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Inside `getView()` `convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon)` is getting called twice remove the one in the end, it's not rquired

Comment: thank you very much..escaped my attention, hope it solves.

Comment: If it does then let me know i'll post it as an answer and you can approve it as the right answer :)

Answer (score -1):

```
try this :

String imageUrl ="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/android- icon/loading.gif"; 
public static int calculateSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
        // width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
        // guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}





      InputStream in1 = convertURLtoInputStream(ImageUrl);
  InputStream in2 =      convertURLtoInputStream(ImageUrl);


      final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
      options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

      BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in1, null, options); 
      options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSize(options, imgWidth , imgHeight);


     options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
     bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in2, null, options);
                        bitmapList.add(bitmap);
```